# How to send widget to front in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to raise image 1 to the top, over everything else. I tried doing `canvas.tag_raise(image_1)`, but unfortunately that did not work. What's wrong with the aforementioned command?

```
canvas = Canvas(
    self,
    bg = "#FFBBFF",
    height = 605,
    width = 851,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
canvas.create_rectangle(
    0.0,
    0.0,
    851.0,
    605.0,
    fill="#2C3440",
    outline="")

self.image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
image_1 = canvas.create_image(
    424.9048767089844,
    445.15918731689453,
    image=self.image_image_1
)
```

Comment: The parameter you need to pass to `.tag_raise()` is the result of the `.create_XXXX()` call that originally created the canvas item - `image_1` in your code.  You may need to save it as something like `self.image_1` so that it's still available when you need it.

Comment: It's already defined as `self.image_image_1`, and when I put that inside the `tag_raise()` function, it doesn't work either. Do you know what's causing `self.image_image_1` to fail as well?

Comment: `self.image_image_1` is the image itself, NOT the canvas item that displays that image.  The two objects are not interchangeable!

Comment: Oh I see. So what should I equal `self.image_1` to? Is it `image`?

Comment: If `tag_raise` doesn't work then try `canvas.lift(image_1)`

Comment: Use `canvas.tag_raise(image_1)` if it will be inside same function of `image_1 = canvas.create_image(...)`.  If it will be called inside other function, both `image_1` and `canvas` should be changed to `self.image_1` and `self.canvas`.